# Looping through many search terms and matching to another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, match

I use a third party to collect data in order to produce a monthly report. In this example, the data dump from the third party is in the sheet called "Data" and the report sheet is called "Month"

Sheets("Data")   This is the data dump of unstructured data listed by segment, although the order of the segments do not match my report:

[image]

Sheets("Month")   This is the structured reporting sheet that lists data by segment appropriate for the report. Copied data from the 'Data' sheet will be pasted into columns O through S

[image]

**I am looking to write a loop that can search through "Data", find each successive word in column B "Month" and paste the appropriate information from "Data" into "Month".**

Right now, I have a long code that works, but it is easily broken if one of the segment names change. This is a small piece that just focuses on Segment 4.

```
Sub Macro1()

' Macro1 Macro
' For post onto StackOverflow

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim qb As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month")
Set qb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")



'To find Segment 4
  With ws
   Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:="Segment 4", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
  If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
       aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = qb.Range("B2")
    Else
        MsgBox "Segment 4 Not Found"
    End If

qb.Range("B2:F2").Copy
aCell.Offset(0, 13).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
End With

End Sub
```

**Is there a way I can loop through Column B in "Month" and match it to data in Column A in "Data" without having to write a search for each Segment?**

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a `For Each` loop going through column A of Data:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ' Macro1 Macro
    ' For post onto StackOverflow

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim qb As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Month")
    Set qb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    qb.Activate

    Dim dataCell As Variant
    For Each dataCell In qb.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(qb.Cells(qb.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 1))
        With ws
            Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=dataCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                     MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                Range(aCell.Offset(0, 1), aCell.Offset(0, 5)).Value = Range(dataCell.Offset(0, 1), dataCell.Offset(0, 5)).Value
            Else
                MsgBox dataCell.Value & " Not Found"
            End If
        End With
    Next dataCell
End Sub
```

Comment: bobajob, THANK YOU. The For Each was just what I needed to complete the task. Your help is much appreciated.